# Resizing the curses terminal doesn't resize the program window

Tags: python, curses

I'm on Windows, where the curses module is not native, so I am using the Windows curses module for python 3.2, found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses).

My goal is to resize the terminal, which is currently at a small 25 lines x 80 columns size.  First I tried the `curses.resizeterm(lines, cols)` command, which is apparently not found in the windows curses module (and `hasattr(curses, 'resizeterm')` returned false).  So I look at the alternative module unicurses, which is also for windows, but that doesn't even have a resize command.

So I do more reading and learn about the environment variables `'LINES'` and `'COLS'` which, when set by `os.environ`, should resize the terminal.  And they do, kind of.  The terminal itself gets resized, but the Windows program displaying the terminal is still the same size as before, 25 x 80.  I have confirmed that the two variables have indeed been changed, writing a little thing to display them in the top left corner.  In addition, the `box()` function does draw a border around the screen as if it the variables were changed.

So, can anyone explain either 1) how to resize the "Windows window" to match the terminal or 2) how to get `resizeterm()` to work on my python installation?  The relevant code of my program and a picture of how it looks are attached below.

[image: console screenshot]

```
import random, sys, math, curses, os
from curses import *

curses.use_env(True)
os.environ['LINES'] = "80"
os.environ['COLS'] = "60"

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.start_color()
stdscr.keypad(1)
curses.curs_set(0)

LINES, COLS = stdscr.getmaxyx()
```

Comment: Just a note, I believe that the standard Windows command-line interface is fixed to 80 columns wide and this cannot be changed.  (I may be wrong though.)

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  All I had to do was right click on the border, and [set a new size under properties](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19982/how-to-make-the-windows-command-prompt-wider/).  Thanks for the hint Armin Rigo, though you deserve an upvote!

Comment: Ah, figured out how to do it in the program itself.  `os.system("mode con cols=80 lines=60")` worked perfectly.

Comment: @Johan it's perfectly OK to post answers to your own questions. It's even perfectly OK to mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help:

```
 import curses

 screen = curses.initscr()

 # Check if screen was re-sized (True or False)
 resize = curses.is_term_resized(y, x)

 # Action in loop if resize is True:
 if resize is True:
     y, x = screen.getmaxyx()
     screen.clear()
     curses.resizeterm(y, x)
     screen.refresh()
```